# integer comparison incorrect or not comparing

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I have an array as such:

```
int array[] = { 1,3,2,5,4,7,6,9,8,10 };
```

When I try to step through the array and compare the numbers none of them trigger the if condition thereby triggering the swap:

```
for( int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > array[i++])
    {
    cout << "Swapping" << array[i] << " " << array[i++]<< endl;
    int temp = 0;
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i++];
    array[i++] = temp;
    temp = 0;
}
```

}

Is there some detail of comparing integers that I am missing? Are they treated differently because they are in an array?

Comment: Just replace every `i++` with `i+1` and it should work

Comment: @FlorianSowade Except, of course, the `i++` in the for itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i++` means "return `i` and set `i = i + 1`". So each time you're using `i++` you are increasing `i` by one which ruins the loop. use `i+1` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`i++` is a post-increment, and returns the previous value.

```
 if (array[i] > array[i+1])
```

Right now, you're comparing `array[i]` with itself.

You also need the following:

```
temp = array[i];
array[i] = array[i+1];
array[i+1] = temp;
```

Comment: As written, the code has undefined behavior in the comparison.  There's absolutely no guarantee that he is comparing `array[i]` with itself.  (In fact, one obvious generation would have him comparing `array[i+1] < array[i]`.)  And the last bit of code would be better handled by `std::swap(array[i], array[i+1[)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing your i too many times.
Change your if statement to:

if ( array[i] > array[ i + 1 ] )

and fix all the other increments likewise apart from the one in your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions:

```
array[i] < array[i++]
```

and

```
array[i] = array[i++]
```

is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.  (As others have pointed
out, it's probably not what you want anyway.  As written, you're
incrementing `i` 5 times each time you go through the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code:-

```
for( int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > array[i+1])
    {
     cout << "Swapping" << array[i] << " " << array[i+1]<< endl;
     int temp = 0;
     temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[i+1];
     array[i+1] = temp;
    temp = 0;
    }
}
```

The statement:`if (array[i] > array[i++])` is equivalent to `if (array[i] > array[i])` which doesn't make sense.